# Room database - check if data already exist error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-contentprovider

I want to check if user data is already exist in database with this in activity onCreate(), here is the code:

```
class DetailActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

      private lateinit var favoriteUserRepository : FavoriteUserRepository

      override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

          favoriteUserRepository = FavoriteUserRepository.get()

          GlobalScope.launch {
                val dispatcher = this.coroutineContext
                CoroutineScope(dispatcher).launch {
                    if (favoriteUserRepository.checkFavoriteUser(username)) {
                        // function to show "remove from favorite database" button
                    }
                }
            }

       }
}
```

FavoriteUserRepository class:

```
    private var INSTANCE: FavoriteUserRepository? = null

    fun initialize(context: Context) {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                INSTANCE = FavoriteUserRepository(context)
            }
        }

        fun get(): FavoriteUserRepository {
            return INSTANCE
                ?: throw IllegalStateException("FavoriteUserRepository must be initialized")
        }

    //check favorite function
    fun checkFavoriteUser(username: String) = favoriteUserDao.checkFavoriteUser(username)
```

checkFavoriteUser function in FavoriteUserDao:

```
@Query("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM user WHERE id=(:username))")
fun checkFavoriteUser(username: String): Boolean
```

I have initialize the INSTANCE in content provider, but I got this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
    Process: com.android.githubmates, PID: 19416
    kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property user has not been initialized
```

How can I fix this problem? Thankyou

Comment: There is a lateinit property some where that you didnt show here that has not been initialized

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the code at onCreate(), that is the only lateinit property that I use

Comment: are you sure? search for lateinit var user in the project

Answer (score 0):

Inside onCreate() method first call `FavoriteUserRepository.initialize(this)`, if FavoriteUserRepository is NULL then new instance will be created or else it's okay.
After calling initialize method then call `favoriteUserRepository = FavoriteUserRepository.get()`. You could directly call

```
            CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
            if (favoriteUserRepository.checkFavoriteUser(username)) {
                // function to show "remove from favorite database" button
            }
        }
```

in stead of nested coroutine block.

Answer (score 0):

That is why we need DI. Dagger2/Hilt/Koin etc.
And the exception msg is clear, **lateinit**

You code executes asynchronously, How could you suppose to be sure that when you checkFavoriteUser, the property favoriteUserRepository was inited?

And your next logic may still not that right

```kotlin
 if (favoriteUserRepository.checkFavoriteUser(username)) {
                        // function to show "remove from favorite database" button
                    }
```

Even if the "remove from favorite database" button shows correctly, u clicked the button,deleted the user.Then when this user is inserted again, the "remove from favorite database" button will never show again unless exit and enter.